# Scheduling a persistent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, quartz-scheduler

Let's say I have some DB entity with a CronExpression field:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job")
public class Job {
    ...
    private CronExpression cronExpression;

}
```

What is the best approach to put it onto quartz schedule? I use Spring3 and Hibernate. Basically I could schedule it in my DAO - anytime Job is created or updated - but I would also need to schedule all existed job at application start-up..

Thanks for your advices!

Comment: Do you really want to schedule entity? in quartz you can schedule a job and load the entity if you want or cache it somewhere if you want to reuse the instance.. isn't that enough? I'm not able figure out the requirement.. can you explain more?

Comment: I actually need to execute some a method (on a schedule expressed in Job entity) that will know a Job id - that would be enough

Comment: Can you tell me its business requirements so that you have to implement like that ?

Comment: I have a list of Job entities, they all have cronExpression field, I just need to execute some a service (on the schedule at job.cronExpression) and pass a job there.  that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `DAO/Repository` to get all cronExpression from your storage. I create in memory DAO

```
@Repository
public class JobEntityDao {
    public List<JobEntity> findAll() {
        List<JobEntity> list = new ArrayList<JobEntity>();

        JobEntity job1 = new JobEntity("0 0 12 * * ?");
        JobEntity job2 = new JobEntity("0 15 10 ? * *");
        JobEntity job3 = new JobEntity("0 15 10 * * ?");

        list.add(job1);
        list.add(job2);
        list.add(job3);

        return list;
    }
}
```

And Component to create quartz scheduler based on your cronExpression. I call it `QuartzExecutor`

```
@Service
public class QuartzExecutor {


    private JobEntityDao jobEntityDao;

    @Autowired 
    public QuartzExecutor(JobEntityDao jobEntityDao) throws ParseException, SchedulerException {
        this.jobEntityDao = jobEntityDao; 
        init();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private void init() throws ParseException, SchedulerException {
        List<JobEntity> jobEntities = jobEntityDao.findAll();

        for (JobEntity jobEntity : jobEntities) {
            System.out.println(jobEntity.cronExpression);

            RunMeTask task = new RunMeTask();

            //specify your sceduler task details
            JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
            job.setName("runMeJob");
            job.setJobClass(RunMeJob.class);

            Map dataMap = job.getJobDataMap();
            dataMap.put("runMeTask", task);

            //configure the scheduler time
            CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
            trigger.setName("runMeJobTesting");
            trigger.setCronExpression(jobEntity.cronExpression);

            //schedule it
            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
    }

}
```

you can get `RunMeJob and RunMeTask` code from http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/.
I Know the class design is not good, but my concern is try to solve your problem.

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thanks! But what if JobEntity changes its cronExpression?

Comment: You must make list of scheduler to as QuartzExecutor attribute. and add restart method
When you change the entity, you can call restart method to invoke init method.